# Unable to deploy NodeJS app to GAE correctly

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

The following is my app.yaml file.

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex

automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 2
  max_num_instances: 4
  cpu_utilization:
    target_utilization: 0.6
```

I hae been having a few issues with GCP:

i. In most cases when I deploy, I get 1 instance running instead of the expected 2.

ii. Today, my ONLY deployed GAE version scaled down to 0 instances and is returning 502 server error. (This is not the first occurrence of this incident, previously I resolved this by redeploying to another compute region and once by creating a whole new project)

iii. Now as I am trying to deploy again,I am getting "ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [4] Timed out waiting for the app infrastructure to become healthy."

iv. Previously, some of our website visitors complained that the website is not working, whereas it works just fine for us or other customers. I have myself faced this issue where website is working on one device and just won't load on another device.

Please suggest how to counter these issues.

Comment: Is this your entire app.yaml file? how many rqps is receiving your App Engine Service?

Comment: I do not know about this. Can you point me to some documentation where I can understand and check regarding rqps, if possible?

Comment: that information is available  the app engine main dashboard on the the request by type chart

https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine?duration=P30D&graph=AE_REQUESTS_BY_TYPE